# creating empty 0kb files in jdk1.7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
java.nio.file.Files
```

//destDir-- is the file name with full path

```
Files.createFile(destDir);
```

This src was working fine. Now I imported the same in to another machine. It executes, creates all required folders and files. But the file created is  but its size is 0kb.

No idea why. all looks fine.

Comment: Unclear. What is the difference?

Comment: What did you expect instead of a new, empty file? Because that's exactly what `Files.createFile` does, as its [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) describes.

Answer (score 1):

the *createFile()* method does exactly what you are describing.

the documentation states that it

> Creates a new and empty file...